# Using If statement in python comparing time to a value

Tags: python, if-statement, time, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write a simple code in python which working on the Raspberry pi.
This code is working but I want to make a better code when I turb on LED in different time.
such as 5minutes later turn on the first led and another 5minutes later second led ....
The problem is when I changing the dlay time such as 5minutes or 10minutes, I have to do hard coding and it seems not a good way to do.
I also tried to adding time to timeset but could not find out the solution.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)

try:
  while True:
   timeset = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
   print(timeset)
   time.sleep(5)
   if timeset > "19:11":
    GPIO.output(24, True)
    print('Please take a medicine')
   if timeset > "19:12":
    GPIO.output(6, True)
    time.sleep(10)
    GPIO.output(24, False)
    GPIO.output(6, False)
    time.sleep(0.30)
   #if timeset =="00:23:30":
   # timeset = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)

finally:
   print("clean up")
   GPIO.cleanup()`
```

[https://discuss.tryton.org/t/typeerror-unsupported-operand-type-s-for-int-and-datetime-timedelta/4966](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
I have looked this and tried applying on my code but does not work.

Comment: You should work with datetimes everywhere in your code.
No need to convert timeset to as string.
It's also easier to compare dates using the datetime type, e.g.
`from datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
if now.time() > time(19,11):
    print('Please take a medicine')
`

Comment: timeset = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
I used this one but how can I compare this on IF statement ?
I tried below code but does not work.
if timeset > datetime.now() + timedelata(minutes=5):

Answer (score 2):

You could go with a basic state machine.

Keep just sleep periods. No need anymore to deal with dates.

Example :

```py
import time

i = 0
state = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    state = i%3
    if state == 0:
        print("light on led A")
    elif state == 1:
        print("light on led B")
    elif state == 2:
        print("light on led C")
    i += 1
```

`i` increments forever
At each loop iteration thanks to the modulo function, `state` changes value in a cyclic way : 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
For each state value it's up to you to do whatever you decide with the RPi leds.